# Transitions on :before & :after & border rendering

Tags: css, pseudo-element

Do transition times stack when using :before and :after? It seems like the transitions for the :before/:after are waiting for the main element's transition to complete prior to beginning their transition.

```
a:after,a:before,a{
    -webkit-transition:all 300ms ease-in-out;
            transition:all 300ms ease-in-out }
a{
    color:red;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:28px;
    font-size:1.75rem }
a:hover{
    border-bottom:1px solid blue;
    border-bottom-width:.0625rem;
    color:blue }
a:after{
    padding-bottom:10px;
    padding-bottom:.625rem;
    border-bottom:1px solid white;
    border-bottom-width:.0625rem;
    content:':after' }
a:hover:after{ border-bottom-color:blue }
a:before{
    padding-bottom:5px;
    padding-bottom:.3125rem;
    content:':before' }
a:hover:before{
    box-shadow:0 4px 2px -2px blue;
    box-shadow:0 .25rem .125rem -0.125rem blue }
```

I'm sure it's something simple that I'm overlooking, it's usually the case.

[Fee Fie Fiddle Foe](http://jsfiddle.net/mKvuD/4/)

Extra Credit: while on the transitions topic, is there a way to actually get the `border` to transition smoothly? Using CSS? I've managed to do a work around, by way of setting the border color the same as background color, colors seem to transition okay; however, box-shadow looks terrible and going from `border:none` to a `border:1px` seems to forego any transitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The delay will not happen if you explicitly define the colors of the normal state and hover state for the anchor and its pseudo elements. For borders, you could define the color to be `transparent` instead of the background color.

http://jsfiddle.net/myajouri/E8PqJ/

**CSS**

```
.el,
.el:before,
.el:after {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 1s;
}

.el,
.el:before,
.el:after {
    color: blue;
    font-size: 32px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}

.el:before,
.el:after {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.el:before {
    content: "before ";
}

.el:after {
    content: " after";
}

.el:hover,
.el:hover:before,
.el:hover:after {
    color: red;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: I had to make this as the correct answer as I have custom borders for the :before/:after states and the other answer didn't seem to lend help to that area. However, this works very well. As I mentioned in the other comment I, for whatever reason had a memory lapse on the border transparency. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Just take the transitions off the before/after pseudo elements:

```
a {
    -webkit-transition:all 3000ms ease-in-out;
    transition:all 3000ms ease-in-out;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mKvuD/8/

Comment: I don't think this works if you want custom hover stylings on the pseduoelements, does it?

Comment: ah hah, I knew it was something stupidly simple. Good catch, also thanks for the reminder of border:1px solid transparent; I have a multi colored background so that helps immensely. I use it to make arrows, not sure why I didn't think of it in this case. Thanks again.

Comment: Nope, this won't transition the borders of the pseudo elements. http://jsfiddle.net/myajouri/mKvuD/9/

Comment: @myajouri I was a little quick on the trigger there, good eye and thanks for your answer.